# How to use AdMob for Maui?

Tags: admob, maui, maui-blazor

I've done everything from this: https://www.mauiexpert.it/admob-for-maui-made-easy/
But when I running app I get this exeptin:
Java.Lang.RuntimeException: 'Unable to get provider com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAdsInitProvider: java.lang.IllegalStateException:

---

How to solve this problem?

I changed .net 7 to .net 6 , but in vain.
tried different application Id, also vain.